# SQL Server Bulk Insert throw error on null when column does not allow null

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

In SQL Server (I'm using 2016) there is a feature called Bulk Insert which allows you to insert records from a flat file.

When a field in the flat file is null and the field in SQL Server is not marked to allow nulls then Bulk Insert will silently use an empty string during the insert operation.

Is there a way to override this behavior so that when the field is null it uses null instead of empty string. And because the field is not set for null for it to then throw an error?

Why am I asking for this? Well because fields silently get an empty string value inserted and I don't want that.

**NOTE**: I'm strictly referring to use T-SQL using BULK INSERT (not bcp or any other means)

**NOTE**: I've seen [Keep Nulls or Use Default Values During Bulk Import (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-nulls-or-use-default-values-during-bulk-import-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016), what I've described here I could not find in that document. If you feel it does include what I seek, please point out what I'm missing instead of directing me to that document. Thank you.

**NOTE**: Here is simple example (note this is not the table I'm working with just simple example to get the point across)

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableOne](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
)
```

Bulk Insert Command

```
BULK
  INSERT TableOne
      FROM 'R:\TableOne.txt'
            WITH(
                  DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
                  FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
                  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
                )
```

File

```
1
```

So basically in this example it is: 1[Tab][CRLF], where the second column is name and it is null.

Result

[image]

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about how you're bulk inserting -- Management Studio, a T-SQL command, `bcp`? Keeping `NULL`s is an almost universal option, but how to specify it differs with the technology (`KEEPNULLS` for `BULK INSERT`, `-k` for `bcp`, and for SSMS it depends on what task you've picked).

Comment: [Keep Nulls or Use Default Values During Bulk Import (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-nulls-or-use-default-values-during-bulk-import-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: That's amazing. I don't think I've ever seen a page in the docs addressing one specific issue that thoroughly and across technologies.

Comment: @GSerg, Jeroen Mostert, I've seen that page and no it is not amazing as I could not figure out how to do what I described. Also KEEPNULLS is not the answer, I tried and know how that works. Please review my post again.

Comment: Then it would help to make your scenario repro'able -- give the table definition and some sample rows you're trying to insert. All I can imagine is that you're trying to make the import fail when the data is actually functionally indistinguishable from the empty string -- which might be a little difficult. In fact, that might well be impossible unless you put it on the column itself as a constraint (disallowing empty values regardless of how they're getting there, including a bulk insert).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fair enough, I updated with an example, hopefully that gets the point across.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this from just the `BULK INSERT` -- this behavior is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) and there's no option that changes things, as far as I can tell:

> When importing into a character column that is defined with a `NOT NULL`
>   constraint, `BULK INSERT` inserts a blank string when there is no value
>   in the text file.

There's no `TREAT_BLANK_AS_NULL` option or somesuch that would help this scenario along.

The only solution I can think of is adding the constraint and using `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` in `BULK INSERT`. If you are not comfortable marking the column with this constraint permanently (because other scenarios might have a legitimate need to insert empty values or they're already there?) you could add it temporarily:

```
ALTER TABLE TableOne WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Name_NotEmpty CHECK ([Name] <> '');
BEGIN TRY
    BULK INSERT TableOne FROM 'C:\Temp\a.txt' WITH (
        DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
    )
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ALTER TABLE TableOne DROP CONSTRAINT CK_Name_NotEmpty;
    THROW;
END CATCH
ALTER TABLE TableOne DROP CONSTRAINT CK_Name_NotEmpty;
```

Obviously this gets a little uncomfortable if the table is dynamic, you need to treat many columns this way, or you can't actually afford to check constraints. At that point I'd recommend using a proper ETL solution, like an SSIS package.

Comment: @GSerg: No, that answer correctly documents how you can insert `NULL`s *for columns that allow `NULL`s*. The scenario here specifically deals with a column that *doesn't* allow `NULL`s. The thing is that T-SQL will treat blanks as `NULL` only if `KEEPNULLS` is specified *and* the column is nullable. If the column is *not* nullable, `KEEPNULLS` won't do anything and blanks will be treated as blanks.

Comment: that’s right, I agree, I was hoping there was an option to change that behavior. I will review your answer and see if it is viable for my needs.  Although the last statement of your comment should be NULLs will be treated as blanks.  [but I can see how your thinking about the field being blank in the file but I see it as null]

Comment: @Exocomp: `NULL` exists only in a relational database. In the text file, they're empty strings, and by the grace of settings they might be interpreted as `NULL`s. How you want to see them is unfortunately subordinate to how the engine chooses to see them. :-) (Although "blanks" is indeed technically incorrect, since values consisting only of whitespace are distinct from the empty string. I'm not considering those for the moment, since it's complicated enough as-is...)

Comment: I do agree generally what your saying. However, in the context of SQL Server there is a case that suggests it sees it as NULL. If a field for example is of integer data type but everything else is the same as what I've described then bulk insert throws error 'Unexpected NULL value in data file' for that field suggesting that from the perspective of SQL Server it is treating it as NULL and not blank - which is why I was thinking about it as NULL.

Comment: @Exocomp: nobody ever accused T-SQL of being overly consistent -- I guess this is another good illustration of that. Outside the context of bulk inserting, of course, the engine will happily and implicitly convert an empty string to an `INT` of value `0`. As long as we know what we're talking about it's all good.